# An error occurred while installing rugged

Tags: ruby, bundle, gitlab, rugged

when I install the gitlab

> bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres puma aws

i get the error:

---

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake 10.4.2
Using RedCloth 4.2.9
Using ace-rails-ap 2.0.1
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.2
Using minitest 5.3.5
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.1.9
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using actionview 4.1.9
Using rack 1.5.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.1.9
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.1.9
Using activemodel 4.1.9
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using activerecord 4.1.9
Using rails-observers 0.1.2
Using activeresource 4.0.0
Using bundler 1.10.6
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.1.9
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
Using rails 4.1.9
Using acts-as-taggable-on 2.4.1
Using addressable 2.3.5
Using asana 0.0.6
Using asciidoctor 0.1.4
Using attr_required 1.0.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using autoprefixer-rails 5.1.6
Using descendants_tracker 0.0.3
Using ice_nine 0.10.0
Using axiom-types 0.0.5
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using sass 3.2.19
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.3
Using browser 0.7.2
Using cal-heatmap-rails 0.0.1
Using carrierwave 0.9.0
Using hitimes 1.2.2
Using timers 4.0.1
Using celluloid 0.16.0
Using charlock_holmes 0.6.9.4
Using coercible 1.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.6.3
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using colored 1.2
Using connection_pool 2.1.0
Using creole 0.3.8
Using d3_rails 3.1.10
Using default_value_for 3.0.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using warden 1.2.3
Using devise 3.2.4
Using devise-async 0.9.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using diffy 3.0.3
Using doorkeeper 2.1.0
Using dotenv 0.9.0
Using dropzonejs-rails 0.4.14
Using enumerize 0.7.0
Using equalizer 0.0.8
Using escape_utils 0.2.4
Using eventmachine 1.0.4
Using excon 0.32.1
Using expression_parser 0.9.0
Using multipart-post 1.2.0
Using faraday 0.8.9
Using faraday_middleware 0.9.0
Using formatador 0.2.4
Using net-ssh 2.8.0
Using net-scp 1.1.2
Using fog-core 1.21.1
Using fog-json 1.0.0
Using fog-brightbox 0.0.1
Using mini_portile 0.6.1
Using nokogiri 1.6.5
Using fog 1.21.0
Using font-awesome-rails 4.2.0.0
Using foreman 0.63.0
Installing rugged 0.21.4 with native extensions

Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /opt/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for cmake... yes
checking for gmake... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
 -- cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --use-system-libraries
extconf.rb:13:in `sys': ERROR: 'cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo' failed (RuntimeError)
    from extconf.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:49:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:49:in `block in <main>'
    from extconf.rb:46:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:46:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.4 for inspection.
```

### Results logged to /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.4/ext/rugged/gem_make.out

how to fix the problem for continue installing the gitlab? any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more information about the OS and how you installed Ruby.

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-023.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Nov 10 22:19:54 EST 2013

LSB Version: :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release: 6.5
Codename: Santiago

And I installed Ruby follow this step:http://my.oschina.net/xiaokaceng/blog/187573

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found the version of libstdc++.so.6 is too old: 4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64 
When I update to libstdc++.so.6.0.17 
The problem is sloved